# Why is there a text node that contains the database record inside the html page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

so on my website, there is an unwanted text node that contains the record of my databse. There is no tag or element whatsoever on the html code, but somehow it exist.

I reckon it is caused by this line of code:

```
<%= @workspace.items.each do |item| %>

<tr>
    <td><%= item.name %></td>
    <td><%= item.owner %></td>
    <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= item.details %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Edit Item', edit_workspace_item_path(@workspace,item) %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', [item.workspace, item],
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

The view.html.erb:

```
<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @workspace.name %>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>maxitem:</strong>
    <%= @workspace.max %>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>details:</strong>
    <%= @workspace.details %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= link_to 'Edit Phase', edit_workspace_path(@workspace) %>
</p>
<p><strong>Items</strong>
</p>
<p>
    <%= link_to 'Add Item', new_workspace_item_path(@workspace) %></br>
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <th><strong>Name</strong>
        <th><strong>Owner</strong>
        <th><strong>Quantity</strong>
        <th><strong>Details</strong>
    </tr>
    <%= render 'items/item' %>
</table>
<%= link_to 'Back to List of Phases', workspaces_path %>
```

I don't know why this suddenly show up on my website
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSd7M.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= @workspace.items.each do |item| %>
```

is the issue as `<%= %>` in ERB stands for "print this". Should be `<% %>` which will execute the Ruby code without rendering it.